# Lombok @Data and @Builder on same entity

Tags: java, lombok

I am using the following:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

what I want to achieve: for JPA usage, I need a POJO with noArgConstructor, getters/setters and equals/hashCode/toString.

For instance creation (for example in tests) I want to use User.builder().build();

Problem: it does not compile, there seems to be an issue with the NoArgConstructor vs. RequiredFieldsConstructor:

```
Error:(15, 1) java: constructor User in class x.y.z.User cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found:    java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

**Update: The error occurs when I try to create a new entity via `new` ... the builder() works.**

What do I miss? Isn't it possible to use @Data, @Entity and @Builder at the same time?

Comment: Does it work if you define an empty no-args constructor yourself?

Comment: Unfortunately then I get the instant error: Compiler already exists

Comment: Did you try adding both the RequiredArgsConstructor and the NoArgsConstructor?

Comment: Thanks @RoelSpilker, using both annotations worked ... but \@Data doesn't give me fields of parent classes in the builder, so the approach is preety much useless for my case. I will stop worrying about it and continue with custom builders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer my own question by summerizing the comments.

First of all, thanks to @RoelSpilker, you can use Builder and Data together on one Pojo if you explicitly provide AllArgs- and NoArgs- constructors:

```
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @Data
 @Builder
 public class Person {...}
```

But: the builder created for this class will not know any inherited fields. For my use case (having some AbstractEntities) this renders the solution useless and I will stick with manual helpers/builders for now.

Comment: Your answer does not mention the class is a JPA entity, but question says explicitly about entity. If that's the case, you should not use `@Data` and `@Entity` together. Lombok will generate `hashCode()` and `equals()` for you using all fields - `id` included, which should be avoided. Or at least treated with care.

Comment: Lombok is updated now, try `@SuperBuilder` annotation on both parent and child class

Comment: @vikingsteve, So if there is a nested structure of classes, like Employee has a Address, Address has Street, City, State, Country, Zipcode. So here, do you mean to say, you'll have to add `@SuperBuilder` in each & every class?

Answer (score 19):

try this code with lombok version 1.16.18 over :

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

Comment: This is correct example, but generaly you can not use @Data on any @Entity! Equals, hashCode and toString can go to conflict with JPA spec or with "lazy load".

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. So it's better to add  "@Getter",  "@Setter", instead of "@Data".

Comment: @Lubo if we use Data annotation on entity classes, you mean to say it doesn't take care of the field which we mentioned as primary key field, in generating equals and hashcode ?

what do you mean by conflict with JPA spec ?
can you explain more.

Comment: @Hiro_Hamada Hi, I have explained it a bit more in my answer. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58505239/11152683 please. Absolute detailed article is linked there.

Answer (score 9):

Beware of that [data objects aren't entities](https://mdeinum.github.io/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/)! Simply put, there is problem with hashcode/equals (when it considers id fields) and also toString method with lazy loaded parts of entity. For reference you can check [Vlad Mihalceas article](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/).

You should:

- exclude id fields from hashcode/equals
- exclude association fields which are not managed in given entity from hashcode/equals
- exclude all lazy loaded fields from toString method
- exclude fields possibly causing circular references from toString method

For sure read at least something on topic of how does JPA do "[dirty checking](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/)" before beeing confident that your handwritten or generated equals/hashcode method is ok.

Answer (score 0):

In the Lombok documentation it is written:
Person.builder().name("Adam Savage").city("San Francisco").job("Mythbusters").job("Unchained Reaction").build();

Do you use this syntax for your purpose? According to your description it's not the case, and could explain the error you get?

Comment: I do not get the error when I use the builder, I get the error when I use the default constructor (which I have to do since it is an entity). Will update the question.